# How to wait for a Redis connection?

Tags: node.js, redis, queue, kue

I'm currently trying to use Node.js Kue for processing jobs in a queue, but I believe I'm not doing it right.

Indeed the way I'm working now, I have two different services (which in this case I'm running with Docker Compose): one Web API built with Express with sends jobs to the queue and one processing module. The issue here is with the processing module.

I've coded it as follows:

```
var kue = require('kue');
var config = require('./config');

var queue = kue.createQueue({
    prefix: config.redis.queuePrefix,
    redis: {
        port: config.redis.port,
        host: config.redis.host
    }
});

queue.process('jobType', function (job, done) {
    // do processing here...
});
```

When we run this with Node, it sits there waiting for things to be placed on the queue to do the processing.

There are two issues however:

1. It needs that Redis be available *before* running this module. If we run this without Redis already available, it crashes because the host is not accessible and ends the process.
2. If Redis suddenly becomes unavailable, the processing module also crashes because it cannot stablish the connection and the process is killed.

How can I avoid these problems?

My guess is that I should somehow make the code "wait" for Redis, but I have no idea on how to do this.

How can this be done in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise to wait until redis is loaded. Then run your module.

```
loadRedis().then(() => {
  //load your module
})
```

Or you can use generator to "stop" until redis is loaded.

```
function*(){
  const redisLoaded = yield loadRedis();
  //load your module
}
```